# You Have an Error on your SQL Syntax C#.net

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax

Good Day everyone. I'm new to this forum and I would like to ask help on my problem. I am currently creating a program where a user can perform queries themselves or in short terms like a query builder kind of application in c#.net

I'm using `XAMPP` and `Visual Studio 2012`.

I'm trying to create an SQLcommand from strings and try to execute it to fill my datagrid. However I'm getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'emp_code  = 00802' at line 1

My String Query that I made was

```
SELECT * FROM emp_main WHERE emp_code = 00802
```

When i checked online on [Mysql Syntax Checker](http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) there was no error on my syntax.

Here is my code on a Button Click Event

```
string SelStr = "SELECT * FROM " + tbTblName.Text.Trim().ToString() + " WHERE";

List<string> fildz = new List<string>();
List<string> oper= new List<string>();
List<string> valz = new List<string>();

foreach (Control ctrl in this.panel2.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.Name.Contains("tbField"))
    {
        fildz.Add(" " + ctrl.Text.ToString());  
    }
    else if (ctrl.Name.Contains("tbOper"))
    {
         oper.Add(" " + ctrl.Text.ToString());                       
    }
    else if (ctrl.Name.Contains("tbVal"))
    {
        valz.Add(" " + ctrl.Text.ToString() + "AND");
    }                
}

string finalqry = "";
var results = fildz.Zip(oper, (x, y) => x + y).Zip(valz, (x, y) => x + y);
foreach (var item in results)
{
    finalqry += item.ToString();
}
int inx = finalqry.LastIndexOf("AND");

MessageBox.Show( SelStr +  finalqry.Substring(0,inx));
try
{
    string xqry;
    xqry = finalqry.Substring(0, inx).Trim().ToString();               
    DataTable dt = db.DTquer(xqry);

    GridData.DataSource = dt;
    GridData.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

And here is the code in my DB.cs file that throws the error:

```
public DataTable DTquer(string thequer)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MakeCon();
    // getConnection().Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(thequer,getConnection());
    try
    {               
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        getConnection().Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    return dt;  
}
```

Thanks in Advance for all the help.

Comment: What is the type of `emp_code` column?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have multiple errors in your code. With two conditions you don't separe the AND, what if you need to pass a string? Where are the quotes? And if you have a datetime?. This way to build an sql command is doomed to fail in a way or another. Look at parameterized queries instead or just use a ORM

Comment: @SonerGönül emp_code is varchar(10)

Comment: @Steve sorry im really not good in english. I am using all as string and not using parameters. thanks for help i will try to look at parameterized queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to do `xqry = SelStr +  finalqry.Substring(0, inx).Trim().ToString();` ?

(You have appended SelStr when it is shown in the MessageBox but not here)

Comment: this fixed the error message. thanks! but im having a blank datatable. i guess i could figure that out. thanks again